# VBA to copy all top rows from files in the same folder and merge into 1 file

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. Im trying to copy the top row for each file and paste into 1 excel file (output will be many rows). Below VBA doesnt paste anything to the active file.

```
Sub CopyTopRowFromFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    ' Set the folder path
    folderPath = "C:\Your\Folder\Path\" ' Change the path as needed
    
    ' Set reference to the active workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWorksheet = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        ' Open the workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)
        
        ' Copy the top row from the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy
        
        ' Find the last row in the destination worksheet
        lastRow = sourceWorksheet.Cells(sourceWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Paste into the active worksheet
        sourceWorksheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        ' Close the source workbook without saving
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Get the next file
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Inform the user
    MsgBox "Top rows copied and pasted from all files in the folder.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Copy the Same Row From Multiple Files

- `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing this code. It may or may not be the active workbook i.e. if you're running this code from a third workbook, e.g. `PERSONAL.xlsb`, you need to use `ActiveWorkbook` instead or remove `wb` and use `Set sourceWorksheet = ActiveSheet`.
- In your code, you have used `sourceWorksheet` for the destination worksheet and `sourceWorkbook` for the source workbook which is rather confusing. Be more careful when naming variables.
- To make the code more efficient, you could assign the values instead of using `PasteSpecial` and toggle screen updating.
- The following will additionally show a message box alerting the user if no file was found.

**Using Dir**

```vb
Sub CopyTopRowFromFiles()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Your\Folder\Path\"
    Const SRC_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.csv"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1

    ' Get the first file name.
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(SRC_FOLDER_PATH & SRC_FILE_PATTERN)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files matching the pattern """ & SRC_FILE_PATTERN _
            & """ found in """ & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Or:
    'Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook ' the active workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.ActiveSheet
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    With dws.UsedRange
       Set dcell = dws.Cells(.Row + .Rows.Count, "A")
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through the files and open, copy and close...
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, scCount As Long
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) <> 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SRC_FOLDER_PATH & sFileName)
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SRC_WORKSHEET_ID)
        With sws.UsedRange
            scCount = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
        End With
        Set srg = sws.Range("A1").Resize(, scCount)
        dcell.Resize(, scCount).Value = srg.Value
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1) ' next destination row
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFileName = Dir ' next file
    Loop
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    'dwb.Save

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Top rows copied and pasted from all files in folder """ _
        & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Using the *FileSystemObject* Object**

- The following doesn't work on a Mac.

```vb
Sub CopyTopRowFromFilesFSO()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Your\Folder\Path\"
    Const SRC_FILE_EXTENSION As String = "csv"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 1

    ' Reference the 'FileSystemObject' object.
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Reference the source folder.
    If Not fso.FolderExists(SRC_FOLDER_PATH) Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """ doesn't exist.", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(SRC_FOLDER_PATH)
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Or:
    'Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook ' the active workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.ActiveSheet
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    With dws.UsedRange
       Set dcell = dws.Cells(.Row + .Rows.Count, "A")
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through the files and open, copy and close...
    
    Dim fsoFile As Object, FileCount As Long
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, scCount As Long
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        If StrComp(fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile), SRC_FILE_EXTENSION, _
                vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' has required extension
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(fsoFile.Path)
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SRC_WORKSHEET_ID)
            With sws.UsedRange
                scCount = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
            End With
            Set srg = sws.Range("A1").Resize(, scCount)
            dcell.Resize(, scCount).Value = srg.Value
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1) ' next destination row
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            FileCount = FileCount + 1
        'Else ' wrong extension
        End If
    Next fsoFile
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    'dwb.Save

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    If FileCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No " & SRC_FILE_EXTENSION & "-files found in """ _
            & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """!", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Top rows copied and pasted from " & FileCount & " file" _
            & IIf(FileCount = 1, "", "s") & " in folder """ _
            & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, the code had a few mistakes initially. After testing I fixed them and it should now work as expected. You only have to decide between `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: I got the msg no files matching the pattern. Is it because the file naming is random i.e some files are named as such ABCD_20230901.CSV and some are quite long

Comment: Possibly. Check if your path is correct, maybe you have moved the files. I usually right-click in the title bar in Windows File Explorer and select `Copy address`. Also, don't forget to add the trailing backslash (\\). You could use the `FileSystemObject` object instead of `Dir` if you're using Windows. Are you?

Comment: I've added a solution that uses the *FileSystemObject* object instead of *Dir*. Give it a try.